# iOS Table View beginUpdates visual bug, black cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a bug that I've spent way too much time on myself. Basically, I'm creating an "accordion" Table View based off Apple docs: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_3
The way the code works is that if you tap on a Table View Header, code gets called to add rows to that section.

The only thing that's different is the fact that it's for iOS 5, so for my header views I'm not using the reusable header view stuff.

Basically, every time I click on a header to show my rows, the cells that are added/removed via [tableView beginUpdates]/[tableView endUpdates] turn black. HOWEVER, if I scroll the table view after then it goes back to being normal.

> **Pictures showing this in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Jfk.jpg**

Some code of how I remove cells :

> ```
> // GET THE SECTION INFO
> SWDeviceSectionInfo *deviceSectionInfo = [self.deviceTableSectionInfo objectAtIndex:section];
> ```

```
// "CLOSE" THE SECTION
deviceSectionInfo.open = NO;

// CREATE INDEX PATHS FOR ROWS THAT NEED TO BE DELETED
NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0;i<deviceSectionInfo.rowInfo.count;i++) {

    // CREATE INDEX PATHS FOR EACH ROW
    [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
}

// APPLY THE ROW INSERTIONS
[self.deviceTableView beginUpdates];
[self.deviceTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.deviceTableView endUpdates];
```

Some extra notes:

1. The background for the cells after scrolling table view is that of the Table View (I can't set the BG for cells). The Yellow view is a view on TOP of the cell background that's supposed to be green.
2. If I click on the iOS simulator debug "color" then again, the black cells disappear.
3. I've tried changing "highlighted", "selected" color to random colors and nothing changes. Remains a black cell bug.
4. I've triple checked the code for stuff like adding cells to the wrong section, all of that is seemingly correct.
5. The bug also occurred when I was using the default white cells (no custom nib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a view on top of the table.

To be more specific, the view had clear color background and shadows added to it so it would form an "inner shadow."

That view SOMEHOW caused the table to render completely wrong when it got updated.

Comment: Well my solution was simply finding and removing what caused the bug.

I did not discover how to put a view on top of the table and still make it work. Don't think it's really worth the effort since this is some underlying iOS bug. I'm sure there are other ways to put on a inner shadow. Maybe creating 4 views on the sides of the tableview.